# Having a hard time understadning PMML's targetCategory attribute

Tags: xml, data-modeling, data-mining, svm

I'm trying to draft a PMML document for a support vector machine and I'm confused about the targetCategory attribute for the SupportVectorMachine tag specified at dmg.org. My question is how should this work when there are more than two classifiers? Should there be one targetCategory and additional alternateTargetCategory attributes where needed?

Given the Iris data set, I'm guessing it would be something like this:

```
<SupportVectorMachine targetCategory="Iris-setosa" alternateTargetCategory="Iris-versicolor" alternateTargetCategory="Iris-virginica">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around some more and found the answer to my own question. There's a free application called KNIME that is fairly straight forward to use and generates PMML output. It turns out that the alternateTargetCategory is only used for binary classification. For the Iris data set, the output for the SupportVectorMachine is the following:

```
<SupportVectorMachine targetCategory="1">
  <SupportVectors numberOfAttributes="4" numberOfSupportVectors="3">
    <SupportVector vectorId="1_1_23"/>
    <SupportVector vectorId="1_1_41"/>
    <SupportVector vectorId="2_2_98"/>
  </SupportVectors>
  <Coefficients numberOfCoefficients="3" absoluteValue="-1.2257883098134195">
    <Coefficient value="0.0082595394670607"/>
    <Coefficient value="5.981904829451028E-4"/>
    <Coefficient value="0.008857729950005803"/>
  </Coefficients>
</SupportVectorMachine>
<SupportVectorMachine targetCategory="2">
  <SupportVectors numberOfAttributes="4" numberOfSupportVectors="16">
  ... etc.
```